# Comportamento inesperado ao centralizar div

Tags: html, css

Fiz uma estrutura básica: um wrapper envolvendo 3 divs! Sendo que a primeira flutua para o lado esquerdo, a do meio *teria* a sua margin definida como *0 auto* e a última div flutuando para o lado direito.
O problema é que a div que centralizada não está centralizando corretamente. Ela não respeita a div wrapper.

Esta imagem ajuda a explanar o que estou querendo dizer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inspecionando o elemento, é possível ver que a div do meio não está centralizada em relação a div wrapper. No lado direito, ela se estende até o final, porém, no lado esquerdo, ela é barrada pela div que contém a imagem.

**Código:**

```css
.centralizar{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.centralizar-verticalmente{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.wrapper{
  background-color: #00568F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.logo-esquerdo{
  float: left;
}

.nome-center{
  display: table;
}

.pesquisa-direito{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.pesquisa-direito input{
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo-esquerdo">
    <img width=""" height="100" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110405214729/gta/pt/images/b/b6/Copyright.png" alt="Logo Empresa" />
  </div>
  <div class="nome-center centralizar">
    <img width="260" height=""  src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-1hoRnbqhvRY/VHhNU3oDftI/AAAAAAAAF0M/GnVOIj9VFLA/s1600/Android_Logo.png" alt="Nome Empresa" />
  </div>
  <div class="pesquisa-direito">
    <input type="texx" placeholder="Pesquise aqui" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Por favor, além de solucionar o problema, alguém consegue me explicar o que está acontecendo? Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é porque a propriedade `display: table;` foi adicionada à class `.nome-center`. Existe um montão de maneiras de se resolver isto, mas a maneira mais rápida e mais "*hacky*" de se resolver isso neste caso seria dar um `position:absolute;` à class `logo-esquerdo` em vez da propriedade `float:left;`. Exemplo:

```
.logo-esquerdo{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Exemplo online ► http://jsfiddle.net/xuq32udc

Depois mais tarde podes estilizar isto de maneira a que o logo do lado esquerdo não se sobreponha sobre as outras imagens usando `media queries` para colocar as imagens umas em baixo das outras em ecrãs de pequenas resoluções.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma de solucionar (estava testando aqui e agora vi a resposta do Chun (+1), mas vou postar assim  mesmo :)) é determinando o tamanho relativo das divs internas, retirando o `display:table` e o `padding-left: 20px;`, e alinhar a `div`com `center` no HTML.

O resultado é que a imagem da `div` do meio fica centralizada. (Não sei se é a melhor prática, mas funciona).

```css
 .wrapper{
    background-color: #00568F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    }

    .logo-esquerdo{
    float: left;
    width: 20%
    }

    .nome-center{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .pesquisa-direito{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 20%
    }

    .pesquisa-direito input{
    width: 80%;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo-esquerdo">
            <img height="100" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110405214729/gta/pt/images/b/b6/Copyright.png" alt="Logo Empresa" />
        </div>
        <div class="nome-center" align="center">
            <img width="260" height=""  src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-1hoRnbqhvRY/VHhNU3oDftI/AAAAAAAAF0M/GnVOIj9VFLA/s1600/Android_Logo.png" alt="Nome Empresa" />
        </div>
        <div class="pesquisa-direito">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquise aqui" />
        </div>
    </div>
```